# Salesforce: Creating a User Form using VisualFocre

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, force.com, sfdc

I have below requirement to Create a VF page.
I created a custom object called **DormsApplicants__c** There are several fields but for the purposes of the example we will use only one field called **First_name__c**.

My main need is to create a VF page that will be available to people **outside the organization** (i.e. customers) who can enter data into the form and then create a record in the custom object **DormsApplicants__c**.  For this purpose I created a website (SITE.COM) and then created a VF page (called TEST) I defined this page (TEST) as a home page on the site.

This is my page:

```
<apex:page standardController="DormsApplicants__c" sidebar="false">
<apex:form id="theForm">
<apex:pageBlock title="TEST">
    <apex:inputText title="TEXTBOX1" label="TEXTBOX2"  value="{!DormsApplicants__c.First_name__c}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

[Image A1 - This is what users see outside the organization.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpeCb.png)

When the user tries to click "save" he gets the following error:

[Image B1 - error on save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWAt8.png)

Of course no record is created. I'd love to hear what the problem is?

Comment: This is because of permission for the DormsApplicants__c object and its Fields.

Comment: If you have created a Force.com site in that  Click on the Profile Its is suffixed with "Guset.. "  Click on it Check The Field Level Permission and Object Level Permission. If it is not Provided Check the  Check box for READ, CREATE etc,   Finally do the same for the Site Contact User Profile

Comment: Can you be a little more specific. Where do I set the permissions for a guser user?

Comment: Go to your force.com site that you have created and click on it in detail page On Top there are button View Accessibility  It will takes you the guest profile